# Android how to debug DeadObjectException

Tags: android, exception, android-emulator

I've this exception:

```
03-29 08:55:10.147      150-162/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ Scheduling restart of crashed service com.android.inputmethod.latin/.LatinIME in 5000ms
03-29 08:55:10.177      150-164/system_process W/InputMethodManagerService﹕ Session failed to close due to remote exception
    android.os.DeadObjectException
            at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodSession$Stub$Proxy.finishSession(IInputMethodSession.java:366)
            at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.finishSession(InputMethodManagerService.java:1178)
            at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.clearCurMethodLocked(InputMethodManagerService.java:1190)
            at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.onServiceDisconnected(InputMethodManagerService.java:1210)
            at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doDeath(LoadedApk.java:1102)
            at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1116)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:891)
03-29 08:55:10.187      150-164/system_process W/InputMethodManagerService﹕ Session failed to close due to remote exception
    android.os.DeadObjectException
            at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodSession$Stub$Proxy.finishSession(IInputMethodSession.java:366)
            at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.finishSession(InputMethodManagerService.java:1178)
            at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.clearCurMethodLocked(InputMethodManagerService.java:1194)
            at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.onServiceDisconnected(InputMethodManagerService.java:1210)
            at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doDeath(LoadedApk.java:1102)
            at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1116)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:891)
```

But only on Android Emulator (and genymotion). How can I debug this exception and handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've found the solution.
Into some emulators (Genymotion for example) the virtual keyboard not shown when the fragments shows the EditText widgets so when I rotate the screen (or generally when I recreate the activity) and causes the DeadObject exception.